# What does the error `cannot be named the same as a tuple variant` mean?

Tags: macros, rust

So I am making a ECS based on [simplecs](https://github.com/kvark/simplecs).

I have a macro that generates a entity struct that looks like this:

```
($($name:ident : $component:ty,)*) => {
        /// A collection of pointers to components
        #[derive(Clone, Debug, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
        pub struct Entity {
            $(
            pub $name: Option<($component)>,
            )*
            children: Vec<Entity>
        }
}
```

It is my goal to use serde to serialize the entity, but that left a bunch of ugly None values where the component should be. So I tried to implement a custom serializer that looks like this:

```
impl Serialize for Entity {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where S: Serializer
    {
        let mut num_fields = 0;
         $(
             match self.$name {
                 Some => num_fields += 1,
                 None => {}
             };
          )*
          let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("Entity", num_fields)?;
          // do serialize
          state.end()
    }
}
```

The serializer tries to access a field via a name supplied as a macro argument (`$name`), but when I go to compile this, I get this error

```
error[E0530]: match bindings cannot shadow tuple variants
  |
  |         Some => {}
  |         ^^^^ cannot be named the same as a tuple variant
```

Comment: You are using `Some` instead of `Some(pattern)`. If you don't care about the contents, use `self.$name.is_some()` in an if condition instead of using a match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `self.$name` is correct to access the member variable. As @oli_obk-ker said in the question's comment, the error is due to using `Some` instead of `Some(pattern)`.

```
         match self.$name {
             Some(_) => num_fields += 1,
//               ^~~
             None => {}
         };
//
// even better, use `if self.$name.is_some() { num_fields += 1; }`.
```

However, you don't even need to write your own `serialize`. You could use the [`#[serde(skip_serializing_if = "f")` attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) on a field, which causes the generated code avoid writing it out if `f(&self.field)` returns true.

```
($($name:ident : $component:ty,)*) => {
    /// A collection of pointers to components
    #[derive(Clone, Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
    pub struct Entity {
        $(
          #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]  // <-- add this
          pub $name: Option<($component)>,
        )*
        children: Vec<Entity>
    }
}
```

Comment: This bit me on using an `Ok` for a `Result<(), Error>`.  I thought it a bit odd to need a `_` for a `()`, but I am lazy.